# while bootstrap tooltip active prevents jquery event from firing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, jquery-events

I got an input field that displays a **bootstrap tooltip** when focused.

```
<input id="nombrecurso" name="nombrecurso"
                        data-original-title="Required field!"
                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover"
                        data-delay='{"show":"200", "hide":"0"}'
                        class="form-control input-lg">
<h6 class="count_message pull-right"></h6>
```

The Number of characters remaining for that field is displayed in a near `<h6>`. This counter is updated on a **jquery** `keyup` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
$(document).on("keyup", '#nombrecurso' ,function() {
  $(this).next('.count_message').empty().append($(document.activeElement).attr('maxlength') + ' characters remaining');
  //event code, is doesn't have to be keyup, it happens with 
  //other events such as click

}
```

The problem is when the tooltip is active, the jquery event keyup doesn't fire up and the counter is not updated.

**You can see the problem here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/40detectives/pen/RWdvJw).**

Try to write something in the input with and without the mouse over the input field.

...Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tooltip` dynamically inserts an element after the input, so that `next()` will not match your output element. Use `nextAll()` instead:

e.g.

```
$(this).nextAll('.count_message')
```

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/HiTechMagic/pen/NGJJwY

### notes:

- Inside the keyup handler, you can use `$(this)` and not `$(document.activeElement)`.
- Rather then `empty().append()` use `html()` to set text content (use `empty()` & `append()` with DOM elements to avoid re-parsing HTML).

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

$(document).on("keyup", '#nombrecurso', function() {
  var text_length = $(this).val().length;
  var whatareyoucounting = $(this).attr('maxlength');
  var text_remaining = whatareyoucounting - text_length;
  $(this).nextAll('.count_message').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
});
```

Comment: Wow, it was so evident I cant belive i missed so much time with it :$     ...THANK YOU.

Comment: Took me 10 minutes playing about to figure it out, as debugging a `tooltip`, that vanishes as soon as you move to the DOM inspector, is not easy :)

Comment: Is really recommendable to use html() over .empty().append() ?

Comment: Does the same thing in one operation *for text*. If you were adding DOM elements you would use `append`, but this is plain text (so the parsing overhead is the same). Clarified that note for you.